# looking for a data structure that support relation m-m between two concepts

Tags: data-structures

I am looking for a data structure to model the following relations between two concepts type and entity.
The number of entity and type is more than 100 million.

[image]

The direction of arrow just show that I need access to type with entity and reverse.

I am looking n efficient data structure; otherwise I implemented it with two maps:

*(type,entities)* and *(entity, types)*

Comment: why is 1:5 if you say "The number of entity and type is more than 100 million"??

Comment: I mean each entity has 1:5 types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bipartite graph to model this type of data with adjacency list representation.

You say that you want efficient data structure, what type of operations do you need to perform on this data?

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29) for operations and time complexities.

For the adjacency list implementation, the nodes can be represented in an array. The node name->index number mapping can be stored as a lookup table.
[Reference here .](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

Comment: For instance, I need to find the types of entity1 or entities of type 2.

Comment: Yes, using a graph(adjacency list), you would be able to answer these questions. And a graph would be more memory-efficient instead of using 2 maps.

Comment: @Sary I am not familiar with graph but what about time complexity of search?

Comment: Updated answer with adjacency list details, search can be done in O(1).